# PHP Autoloader and Unix Case-Sensitive File-System

Tags: php, spl, autoloader

I have **index.php**

```
<?php
    include('_controller/Autoloader.php');
    Gold_Autoloader::init();

    $mysql = new Gold_MySQL();
```

**_controller/Autoloader.php**

```
<?php
class Gold_Autoloader
{

    public static $loader;

    public static function init()
    {
        if (self::$loader == NULL)
            self::$loader = new self();

        return self::$loader;
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        spl_autoload_register(array($this, 'controller'));
        spl_autoload_register(array($this, 'resources'));
    }

    public function resources($className)
    {
        $className = preg_replace('#Gold_#', '', $className);
        $className = preg_replace('#_#', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $className);

        set_include_path(PROJECT_ROOT . '_resources');
        spl_autoload_extensions('.php');
        spl_autoload($className);
    }

    public function controller($className)
    {
        $className = preg_replace('#Gold_#', '', $className);
        $className = preg_replace('#_#', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $className);

        set_include_path(PROJECT_ROOT . '_controller');
        spl_autoload_extensions('.php');
        spl_autoload($className);
    }
}
```

And I have file **_controller/MySQL.php** with Gold_MySQL.class.
On windows system this code is working and including MySQL.php, but on hosting this code not working ((

```
[Thu Jan 27 12:55:57 2011] [error] PHP Fatal error: Class 'Gold_MySQL' not found in /home/u91167/youd0main.com/www/index_.php on line 5
```

**EDIT**

How to make so that Unix could look at any files? Zend has no files with a lowercase letter.

Comment: FYI, your usage of DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR is redundant. When including files, Windows will still accept the Unix separator, ie. C:/folder/MyClass.php still works. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR should be used when exploding a system-generated path, like $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. ...Just preference I guess.

Comment: Also, you don't need to use preg_replace as you aren't actually using any regular expressions, switch to str_replace and it will still work the same... just a bit faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like your filename is case sensitive and you're trying to load a file in the wrong case. i.e. you might need `gold_mysql.php` instead of `Gold_MySql.php`?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like a case sensitive problem with the server filesystem.
check paths and filenames for correct case.

linux/unix take care about case.
windows does not.

---

<sub>note: This answers a previous version of the question</sub>

Comment: I think the asker knows that. The question was "How to make so that Unix could look at any files?", not "What's wrong?".

Comment: You are late. My answer is from 27. Jan. 2011 - since my answer the question is modified 4 times. The accepted from 29. Jan. 2011 answer is about case.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Excuse me. The old version indeed asked "What's wrong".

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you're overriding the include path. In your index.php try something like

```
<?php

set_include_path(
    implode(PATH_SEPARATOR,
    array(
        realpath('./_controller'),
        realpath('./_resources'),
        get_include_path()
    ))
);
```

And remove the set_include_path() calls in your Autoloader class.

IMHO, If you are using Zend Framework, it would be better to write two separator autoloaders and push them to Zend's autoloader stack.